# PHP parse error at >0

Tags: php, parsing, syntax-error

Not a programmer, at all.  I was asked to develop an FTP page for our website, and found what looked like a tidy bit of code to make it work.  Unfortunately (I'm using Dreamweaver 6), it appears that the code breaks on line 25 at "if(strleng($error_message)>0)"... what am I missing?

```
<?php
$email_to='info@ispitfire.com';
$email_subject = "New file uploaded to FTP";
function died($error) {echo "There was an error uploading your file.";echo $error;die();}
if(!isset($_POST['theirname']) ||
!isset($_POST['email']) ||
!isset($_POST['audioname'])) {
died('Please make sure your name, email address, and the project name are completed.');
}
$theirname = $_POST['theirname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$audioname = $_POST['audioname'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) {$error_message .= "Please input a valid email address.";
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$theirname)) {
$error_message .= "Please avoid using special characters.";
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$audioname)) {
$error_message .= "Please use only letters and numbers for Project Name.";
}
**if(strlen($error_message)>0){died($error_message);}clean_string($string){**
$bad = array("content-type","bbc:","to:","cc:","href");
return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}
$email_message = "A new file has been uploaded to the FTP site\n\n";
$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($theirname)."\n";
$email_message .= "Title: ".clean_string($audioname)."\n\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n\n\n\n";
$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n";
if ($_FILES["file1"]["error"]>0) {
$email_message .= "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file1"]["error"] . "\n";
}
else
{
$email_message .= "Upload: " . $_FILES["file1"]["name"] . "\n";
$email_message .= "Type: " . $_FILES["file1"]["type"] . "\n";
$email_message .= "Size: " . ($_FILES["file1"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb\n";
if ($_FILES["file1"]["type"] == "") {
if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file1"]["name"])) {
$email_message .= $_FILES["file1"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
}
else
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"],
"upload/" . $_FILES["file1"]["name"]);
$email_message .= "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file1"]["name"];
}
}
else
{
died("Unsupported file type.");
}
}
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
header('Location: ftp.html');
?>
```

This is my first foray into PHP, so I'm really not even sure where to begin with this.  It appears that everything else works properly, but I can't get the upload to work because of something on that particular line.

Comment: delete ** before and after if(strlen($error_message)>0).

Comment: ** are here to show the breaking line,

Comment: died is a function which he defined by himself, @JoachimIsaksson

Comment: @Jonast92 Ah, yes, you're right, I pasted it into autoindent and now I can see it :)

Comment: Is this where you got the original code?:http://www.codercaste.com/2013/01/how-to-create-a-script-to-send-automated-emails-via-php/

Comment: You need to be more clear. What do you mean that your code is "breaking"? Your code is supposed to exit when strlen($error_message) > 0. It should be printing out an error message telling you what's invalid about your input. What error messages are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(strlen($error_message)>0){died($error_message);}clean_string($string){
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Either you're calling the function `clean_string()`, which means the `{` at the end is wrong. If you're trying to DEFINFE `clean_string()`, in which case you're missing `function`.
 e.g.

```
if (...) { ... }
function clean_string($string) { ... }
```

or

```
if (...) {... }
clean_string($string);
```

Comment: it was missing "function."  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What should `clean_string($string){` to do?

Should it be `if(clean_string($string)) {` ?

or `if(!clean_string($string)) {`

or only `clean_string($string); {` ?

or ... ?